# field that is supposed to be assigned by fxml is throwing NullPointerException when accesed from inner class - javaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, inner-classes

I have a controller for an fxml file. The controller has a field `public BorderPane mainBorderPane;` which is supposed to be filled with the Border pane of the same `fx:id` found in the fxml file. When I try to access it from an inner class it gives a `NullPointerExcetion`

The `clearBorderPaneCenter();` and the `clearBorderPaneRight` work just fine but when I run the `cashSceneController.show()` it crashes on the line `mainBorderPane.setRight(rightLayout);`

fxml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="mainBorderPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Program.gui.MainSceneController">
   <top>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
   <left>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </left>
   <center>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
   <right>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </right>
   <bottom>
      <Pane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>
```

Simplified version of controller:

```
public class MainSceneController {

    MainSceneController.CashSceneController cashSceneController = new MainSceneController.CashSceneController();
    public BorderPane mainBorderPane;

    public void switchLayout(byte ID){
        //todo Make this work switchScene()

        clearBorderPaneCenter();
        clearBorderPaneRight();
        cashSceneController.show();
    }

    public void clearBorderPaneRight(){
        try {
            mainBorderPane.setRight(null);
            OutputHelper.log("cleared right of mainBorderPane");
        } catch (Exception e){
            OutputHelper.log("clearing right of mainBorderPane not required - already cleared");
        }
    }

    public void clearBorderPaneCenter(){
        try {
            mainBorderPane.setCenter(null);
            OutputHelper.log("cleared centre of mainBorderPane");
        } catch (Exception e){
            OutputHelper.log("clearing centre of mainBorderPane not required - already cleared");
        }
    }

    public class CashSceneController{
        VBox rightLayout;
        public void show() {
            setVBox();
            mainBorderPane.setRight(rightLayout);
        }

       public void setVBox(){
           rightLayout = new VBox();
           //......
       }
    }
}
```

This is how the fxml file is loaded

```
SceneController = new MainSceneController(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("gui/MainScreen.fxml"))));
```

I hope that I explained my problem well enough. I'm new to stack overflow and have no idea of what is a good question

Edit: it appears that the problem is caused by the `mainBorderPane` not being assigned at all. The `clearBorderPaneCenter` and `clearBorderPaneRight` seem to not crash cause they are caught by the try catch. Any ideas why the mainBorderPane might not be getting assigned correctly?

Comment: I guess `MainSceneController.switchLayout` is part of the stacktrace. Could you add information about how the instance of `MainSceneController` you call the method for is created and how the fxml corresponding to the controller is loaded? Also does the log contain exceptions?

Comment: The first thing that you might want to know is that <code>MainSceneController</code> extends <code>SceneController</code>

Comment: how can I write code here without it coming to a mess?

Comment: Click the [edit] link below the question to modify your post.

Comment: for now this will do as I dont know how to write code blocks here

SceneController
https://pastebin.com/VxbdCwp9

Constructors
https://pastebin.com/tjaAYvMQ

How it's created
https://pastebin.com/Eczy6Zmj

Comment: One thing that seems odd is that you create a controller using `FXMLLoader.load` and then wrap the scene you put the result into in another instance of `MainSceneController`. Probably reading this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/14190310/2991525 would get you some info on how to communicate with a controller.

Comment: BTW: you are calling `switchLayout` on the outer `MainSceneController` instance, i.e. the one assigned to `SceneController` in the last code snippet, I guess?

Comment: @fabian yes I am

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the fxml annotation. It is required for the FXMLLoader to inject the BorderPane into the code

```
    @FXML      
    public BorderPane mainBorderPane;
```

Comment: Not for `public` fields.

Comment: Still the same error. @FXML isn't needed as its already public

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that.
Could you show us the code on your scene setup?